# Data type in sybase function replace() instead of value

Tags: sql, function, sybase, netezza

Hi I have a Sybase sql query where function replace() is used like this `replace(Table1.Col1,char(10),'')` 
When transfering the query to Netezza There is a problem at the beginning of char(10). 
I dont understand what was the char(10) for ? From Sybase manuals : REPLACE ( original-string, search-string, replace-string )  there should be a search string but instead there is a data type.

What could I replace with this char(10) that Netezza would accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Replace` isn't native in Netezza however it is included in the `Netezza SQL Extensions Toolkit`

Replace Works like the example below:

```
replace('ORIGINAL VALUE','VALUE TO REPLACE','REPLACE WITH THIS')
replace(Table1.Col1,' ','')
```

In the second example the function will replace any space with nothing.